# A complicated recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recurrence-relations

I have recently been met with the recursive sequence of the form $a_1=1, a_2=1, a_{n+2}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}a_{n+1}+\frac{2}{n+2}a_n+\frac{1}{n+2}$, and I have no idea on how to find its general form. What are the steps I need in order to do so?

Comment: You may want to check https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0022247X97959035?token=362FDE504C80510D38136466E630CEC1F264B723BEB286CBA6ACBDFC029CB2575B0926E9FED2E617CD7AB8BB5B016074&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20211111175250

Comment: In principle you could treat it as a second order difference equation and try to solve for $a_{n}$.

Comment: How about let $b_n=na_n$?

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera It would be straightforward if the coefficients were constant, but it is not the case.

Comment: @Nightflight That transformation makes it simpler, but the coefficients are still not constant.

Comment: @PierreCarre it would be easier if instead of $\frac{2}{n+2}a_{n}$ there was $\frac{n}{n+2}a_{n}$.

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera I agree with you , as if it'll be instead of  $a_n=\frac{n-1}{n}a_{n-1}+\frac{n-2}{n}a_{n-2}+\frac{1}{n}$ in $a_n=\frac{n-1}{n}a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{n}a_{n-2}+\frac{1}{n}$ . Then we can easily let $a_n=\frac{b_n}{n}$ and then , we can observe that $b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}+1$ which is nothing but $b_n=F(n)+1$ where $F(n)$ is $n^{th}$ Fibonachhi number , i.e. given by $b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n$